# How to Make an automatic computation of timework?

Tags: vb.net

Hi im trying to make a project that display the computed timein/timeout of all the data in datagridview and then print it on a crystal report..i just dont have idea how to do it =(

my design is i have a dropdown box to select the employee, month calendar to select the month(its like a filter for my datagridview), 
then datagridview that display their time and lastly a 
button that will print preview the data in a datagridview

Comment: So I am confused, you are saying the user (read: employee) will pick a month, then a day with their total hours worked that day with a print button? Then the `Crystal Reports` report will determine the their `timein` and `timeout` for that day? You will use summary data to generate detail data?

Comment: ok to make it simple.. the admin select the employee in the dropdown then it will display all the timein/timeout of that employee now if the admin select like the month in Monthcalendar it will filter the data in datagridview with the selected month..

Comment: i manage to do that and what im trying to do now is to display the computed timein/timeout of all the data in datagridview and then print it on a crystal report..i just dont have idea how to do it =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT CAST(punchout_dt AS Date) AS work_date,
        SUM(DateDiff(second, punchin_dt, punchout_dt) / 3600.0) as hours_worked
   FROM HoursLogTable
        WHERE user_name = @UserName
        AND CAST(punchout_dt AS Date) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
        GROUP BY CAST(punchout_dt AS Date)
        ORDER BY CAST(punchout_dt AS Date)
```

This is presuming that you're using SQL Server:  every DB platform will have different functions to calculate the number of seconds between two DateTimes.

Comment: ahmmm punchout is a datatable? = date datatype? correct? and worl_date is? im kinda confused..but let me try doin that in my test db

Comment: can you make a sample table and data so i can query it easily..much appreciated if you do that =)

Comment: @daniloJR What data do you have? Is there a database you have in place with the data you wish to report on? Or are you building from scratch?

Comment: @Curt that is actually what i need but it seems that the query is not working in my sql >.<

Comment: Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' punchout_dt) / 3600.0) as hours_worked
   FROM HoursLogTable
        WHERE us' at line 2

Comment: If you go to the sqlfiddle link I posted, you'll see that it's working just fine...

Comment: yeah its working in sql server..but i think its not gonna work in my sqlyog trial version =(